# Import key/value data from multiple files, combing the keys in a common column

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I have key/value data in text files. Some of the keys are present in all the files, some are not.

For example:

`file1.txt`

```
first;1
second;2
third;3
```

`file2.txt`

```
first;11
new;123
second;22
```

I want to import the data from those files into Excel in such a way that the keys from all the files would be placed (and combined) in a common column. The values should be in their own column (one column for each file).

The sheet should look like this.

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to avoid preprocessing the files or utilizing macros. I can, however, change the format of the files (e.g. to XML), if that makes it easier.